How do I implement JWT authentication across multiple REST services in Django REST Framework?
I'm going to end up having multiple microservices for this project (calculation, customer, and others).  The workflow is: the user logs in, gets the JWT, and then will be making multiple calls to the various services as long as the token has not expired.
I have created an authentication service in DRF using Simple JWT.  The token call and refresh work great.  I'm entirely new to DRF, so I don't know the best way to do this.  How do I implement it so that the other services know that the token is valid?  Architecturally, each microservice will be hosted in its own container in AWS.  Is this something for which I could leverage AWS' API management?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Okay, so #1 is how I'm currently setup. That's the default SimpleJWT implementation. That's working in and of itself. #2 I think is out, as no API calls can occur until the user logs in - no sharing or public key. #3 seems to be the answer and is similar to other APIs I've worked with. My only question there, is how does the microservice on one container know what the authorized JWT is running in the auth service on another container? Is that where something like AWS API Manager or Apigee comes in? I think I'm trying to solve this from a code perspective when it's really infrastructure.
